# dropna() in large pandas CSV casues KeyError: MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DF loaded by pd.read_csv(). 500mb, 4 columns, 50xxx rows. I need to delete all rows with `0` or `-` (gap) in 3th (Allele1 - AB) or 4th (Allele2 - AB) columns.

My code:
*Read CSV*

```
data_skipped = pd.read_csv(cwd + file_list[i], sep='\t', skiprows = row_skipped_value, header = 0, index_col = False, dtype=object, low_memory = True)
```

*Deleting gaps*

```
fixed_data = fixed_data.loc[fixed_data['Allele1 - AB' or 'Allele2 - AB'] != gap].dropna()
```

After deleting gaps line i got error:

```
KeyError: MemoryError()
```

If I delete that line, all it's fine and next steps works fine (but in result I have files with gaps). 14GB free RAM.

Any advise or solution?

Comment: Are you sure `fixed_data.loc[fixed_data['Allele1 - AB' or 'Allele2 - AB'] != gap]` will work? Shouldn't it be `fixed_data.loc[(fixed_data['Allele1 - AB'] != gap) | (fixed_data['Allele2 - AB'] != gap)]`?

Comment: I have a different file formats, and when I try it on smaller files, everything is fine. Gaps are deleting. But in this example yours code work. Thank u very much !
In this case, I will change that part of the code in scripts for others files :)

Comment: Are you still getting `MemoryError`?

Comment: No, ur code repair everything :D thank u very much. All works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not do what you want.

**Pandas does not use `and`, `or` etc. as boolean operator.** See [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These **must** be grouped by using parentheses

So you should filter data in this way. Instead of:

```
fixed_data = fixed_data.loc[fixed_data['Allele1 - AB' or 'Allele2 - AB'] != gap].dropna()
```

Do:

```
fixed_data.loc[(fixed_data['Allele1 - AB'] != gap) | (fixed_data['Allele2 - AB'] != gap)].dropna()
```

And this does not require additional import of other packages.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using

```
fixed_data.loc[fixed_data['Allele1 - AB' or 'Allele2 - AB'] != gap].dropna(inplace=True)
```

, and not reassigning it (it will return `None`).
In that case no copy of the array will be created, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Update:
I think your code does not make that much sense in the first place. `'Allele1 - AB' or 'Allele2 - AB'` will always evaluate to `'Allele1 - AB'`.
I am guessing you want to drop all rows containing `NaN` and only keep rows where column `Allele1 - AB` is not equal to `gap` and `Allele2 - AB` is not equal to `gap`.

In that case use:

```
import numpy as np
fixed_data = fixed_data[np.logical_or(fixed_data["Allele1 - AB"] != gap, fixed_data["Allele2 - AB"] != gap)].dropna()
```

Comment: Thank u for advice, I will learn about it more. :) But code it's still not working. I got the same error in the same line :/ What else can cause it?

Comment: See update. Your code does not do what you want I think